# Show only collections which have documents inside in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

Is it possible to get the list of the collections name which have at least one document? 
I mean to not list the collections which don't have any document.

Answer (score 0):

`listCollections` command allows [filtering](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/listCollections/) but the filters must be over the returned fields, and I don't see any field that returns the size of the collection.

Therefore you most likely need to query each collection with a `find` to find out if it has any documents.